# 301 redirects to a similar domain

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, web-crawlers

My company has two similar but not identical sites. Similar page hierarchy and content but different brands. We want to shut one down and 301 the pages to what we feel is relevant on the better site. 
Has anyone ever done this before and if so do you know roughly how long we can expect to get SEO traffic on the better site as a result of redirects for the likes of Google? How quickly will Google start to de list the redirected site?

Comment: Well I can answer your second question at least. Google will immediately start to de-list the redirected site as soon as it crawls it. The new site will gain a good SEO bump at first I think, then continue to gain SEO as the redirects set in over several weeks/months. But I don't have any experience with the timeline, it's just an idea.